# Use video formats for animated content

Tags: html, html5-video, gif

I have a gif image on my website and I added it like this and it's working.

```
<img src="assets/images/banner-gif.gif" alt="hero-banner" class="bannerImg">
```

Now I check the website performance on [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) then I am getting the message

> Use video formats for animated content

[image]

Then I tried the below code but it's not working.

```
  <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <img src="assets/images/banner-gif.gif" alt="hero-banner" class="bannerImg">
</video>
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This says that you better to use MPEG4 video format instead of GIF. You can convert your GIF to MGPEG4 by converters such as [Converter](https://ezgif.com/gif-to-mp4)

You cannot use GIF in `<video>` tag. Convert file to MPEG4 and save that as video.mp4 file name. Then use it in `<video>` tag

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Let me try this.